# Complicated MySQL Query taking forever to execute

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've a somewhat suboptimal database structure I have to work with. Table1 contains 2 Ids (lets call them id1, id2). These Ids link to 2 rows in another table Table2. I want to get some columns of Table1 and use id1 and id2 to get columns out of Table2. Do I really have to join the same table twice to link to different rows or is there another more efficient way to do this? My queries take over 30 seconds for 20 rows.

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.name, t3.name
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table2 t3
WHERE t1.id1 = t2.id AND t1.id2 = t3.id AND t1.index = 2
```

Comment: When you say "20 rows" is that the size of the tables or the size of the result set?  If the latter, how large are the tables?  What is their structure?  Also, you need to learn ANSI standard join syntax, with the `on` clause for the conditions.  `where` clauses for `join`s are so passe.

Comment: My code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/1uZnRuJw It returns valid data, but takes more than 30 seconds for about 1000 total rows in those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it should be possible to use JOINS:

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.name FROM 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 
ON t1.id1 = t2.id OR t1.id2 = t2.id 
WHERE t1.index = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this [Many-to-Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relation, please try [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT t2.id    AS t2_id, 
       t3.id    AS t3_id, 
       t2.name  AS t2_name, 
       t3.name  AS t3_name
  FROM Table1      t1
  JOIN Table2      t2
    ON t1.id1   =  t2.id
  JOIN Table3      t3
    ON t1.id2   =  t3.id
 WHERE t1.index =  2
```